# Calling web service asynchronously (C#) - completed event breakpoint not hit

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

Can't get to the bottom of this one and it's obviously something daft, could anyone help please?

I'm calling a web service asynchronously using a C# console application, and a breakpoint in the 'completed' event is never getting hit.

Here's the example code, really simple:

```
public static void CallWebservice()
    {

        try
        {
            ServiceReference1.GlobalWeatherSoapClient proxy = new GlobalWeatherSoapClient();

            proxy.GetCitiesByCountryCompleted += proxy_GetCitiesByCountryCompleted;

            proxy.GetCitiesByCountryAsync("France");

        }
        catch (FaultException faultException)
        {
            var error = faultException.Message;
        }

    }

    static void proxy_GetCitiesByCountryCompleted(object sender, GetCitiesByCountryCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

So the breakpoint on the line

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

is never hit.

However if I add an additional line after the actual asynch call:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

..the breakpoint is now getting hit OK. Can anyone explain what's going on here? Obviously something to do with threads and the debugger, but I don't understand what?

Comment: What happens after `CallWebservice` is called? Will the application exit?

Comment: don't you have to await your GetCitiesBYCountryAsync()? i think it returns a tasks

Comment: @Batavia - Possibly not because it doesn't sound as though OP using `async/await` but the original async pattern where you have a call-back in which case my answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `proxy` is going out of scope and so being cleaned up (therefore losing your callback).

So, you need to move your Proxy OUT of the call so that its lifetime is controlled by you:

```
private ServiceReference1.GlobalWeatherSoapClient _proxy; 

public void CallWebservice()
{
    try
    {
        _proxy = new GlobalWeatherSoapClient();
        _proxy.GetCitiesByCountryCompleted += proxy_GetCitiesByCountryCompleted;
        _proxy.GetCitiesByCountryAsync("France");
    }
    catch (FaultException faultException)
    {
        var error = faultException.Message;
    }
}

public void proxy_GetCitiesByCountryCompleted(object sender, GetCitiesByCountryCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something here
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This is not a perfect example as without seeing rest of your code I can't tell you where to instantiate `proxy`. Not in `CallWebservice` but in a constructor etc but hopefully you get the idea!

Comment: If you're going to down-vote at least give a reason. It is not constructive to just say "NO" without saying why you disagree with an answer? Care to expand whoever that was?

Answer (score -1):

You should await on the call to `proxy.GetCitiesByCountryAsync("France")`, otherwise you'll come out of the try block before the function completes.

Comment: I don't think `await` is the right answer here because it looks like OP wants to exit method and get callback else where.